# ssh access for non-admin users at ESXI 5.5

Tags: virtual-machine, esxi

I'm using ESKI 5.5. 
Is it possible to grant SSH access to a local user which has not the role Administrator?
Actually I scp the inventory xml to get the MOE ids. I'd like to put that in a script and give it to users without root access.

Answer (score 0):

ssh access is given based on **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** in linux. if you want to allow ssh to some user add the user's name in it somewhere in the last line.

> for example.
>
> > AllowUsers user1@10.0.10.0 user2@192.30.2.3

Comment: good idea but then this made it impossible to login as root. I gonna check the sshd man pages. Before I was looking for a button in the vSphere client ;)